# MSVS command line arguments

Tags: c, visual-studio, command-line-arguments

[image: Yo.txt]

```
#include "hmap.h"

int main(char* argv[], int argc)
{
    printf("%s", argv[0]); <---- fails here
    system("pause");
    fileOpen(argv[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

I am using MSVS 2012. I'm wondering if I'm using the command line arguments wrong. The text file is in the same folder. All my header file has is the #include libraries I will using, some #define's I'll be using, and extern function prototypes.

When I run the program it says "expand.exe has stopped working...."

I usually program in a Linux environment using GCC but I'm trying to learn MSVS environment. Getting a little frustrated on how much of a hassle to input command line arguments :.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the arguments for `main()` are around the wrong way.

That is, the first argument should be the argument count (`argv`), and the second one the argument vector (`argv`).

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {}
```

It fails because a subscript should be used only with an array or pointer.